# How direct was the Enlightenment's role in the French Revolution?

Tags: france, 18th-century, french-revolution, revolution, enlightenment

John Thomson, in his book "Europe after Napoleon", argues that the Enlightenment had little direct role in creating the conditions for revolution. Neither the thinkers prescribed revolution nor the readers wanted a revolution. How to analyse or examine this?

Are the ideas only used as justification rather than acting as motivators?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].